# Correct VHDX sector size in Hyper-V enviroment for a RAID array

Tags: raid, hyper-v, hardware-raid, vhd, lsi

What is the correct sector size (which available in Powershell as options, when creating a new vhdx) for RAID10 array with default stripe size? I am using LSI 9271-4i controller and 4x Seagate ST3300657SS in Hyper-V 2012 R2 enviroment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends more on what guest OS you intend to use the VHD with than it does on the physical storage subsystem.  (In general, with virtualization, you want to separate the physical characteristics from the virtual characteristics, so that you can move your VM from one host to another.)

If your guest OS supports 4K disks, then you'll probably get better performance for a big VHD by using 4K sectors.  If your guest OS doesn't support 4K disks, you'll be really frustrated if you use them.

And if the VHD is small, then probably none of this matters much.  4K disks are a much bigger deal when the disk is large.

Comment: VM Guest OS will be Windows Server 2012 R2. And typical VHDX size will be around 30GB for OS and 400GB for data.

Comment: Those are tiny.  I doubt that you'd see much difference.